# Any python methods/package to force convert text to string format, automatically taking care of all issues?

Tags: python, string, text, pip

Here's an example:

*The Chittagong Club was a colonial relic, a gated remnant of the Raj, the era of British rule. On
its veranda, the wives of English tea planters once sipped their gin and tonics and complained
about the natives, in scenes reminiscent of E. M. Forster’s A Passage to India. Twenty-three
years had passed since the dismantling of British rule on the subcontinent and the subsequent
partition of British India into Hindu-majority India and Muslimmajority Pakistan. The only thing
that had changed at the Chit-tagong Club was the members’ skin color. Waiters in white gloves,
turbans, and tightfitting trousers called churidars continued to serve roast beef, curries, and
mulligatawny soup. The postcolonial elites of East Pakistan, Abed among them, had adopted the
habits of the former rulers, including a set of arcane club rituals. Membership required a
recommendation from a current member and an appearance at an initiation ceremony in black tie
and cummerbund. One could be blackballed for failing to meet the club’s standards. Abed, a
pipe-smoking Anglophile in a pinstriped suit, who had spent fourteen years in Britain and could
recite Shakespearean soliloquies, easily made the cut. A bachelor with no family to go home to,
he dined at the club three nights a week.*

If you were to take this and paste it into your ide, putting quotation marks around it; it wouldn't work as there's a lot of issues with symbols and stuff within the text body itself that you have to go through one by one. Happens all the time when you copy random pieces of text into python. Any python method or package that just converts whole pieces of text like this to string data type automatically?

Beginner coder here, please forgive me if i sound dumb or arrogant in any way. I genuinely don't know of a better way to phrase my question yet.

Comment: This looks like perfectly fine text. Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what "issues with symbols and stuff" you mean specifically?

Comment: @mistermiyagi sorry if i seem rude or ignorant, absolute python and programming beginner here. if you put big pieces of text in and put one pair of quotes around it, it always gives errors and doesn't convert the text to string entirely. Gives you lots of stuff within the text you have to go though and change individually. Was looking for an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this you can wrap your text in triple quotes and it will be treated as a single string. For example

```
text = """The Chittagong Club was a colonial relic, a gated remnant of the Raj, the era of British rule. On its veranda, the wives of English tea planters once sipped their gin and tonics and complained about the natives, in scenes reminiscent of E. M. Forster’s A Passage to India. Twenty-three years had passed since the dismantling of British rule on the subcontinent and the subsequent partition of British India into Hindu-majority India and Muslimmajority Pakistan. The only thing that had changed at the Chit-tagong Club was the members’ skin color. Waiters in white gloves, turbans, and tightfitting trousers called churidars continued to serve roast beef, curries, and mulligatawny soup. The postcolonial elites of East Pakistan, Abed among them, had adopted the habits of the former rulers, including a set of arcane club rituals. Membership required a recommendation from a current member and an appearance at an initiation ceremony in black tie and cummerbund. One could be blackballed for failing to meet the club’s standards. Abed, a pipe-smoking Anglophile in a pinstriped suit, who had spent fourteen years in Britain and could recite Shakespearean soliloquies, easily made the cut. A bachelor with no family to go home to, he dined at the club three nights a week."""

len(text.split(" "))
# 206
```

Comment: [triple-quoted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), that's a good hint, +1

Comment: It looks like single double-quotes are perfectly fine here. Why recommend triple double-quotes?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In this specific case plain double-quotes would work, but it seemed clear to me that this was just one example, and there could be other examples that contained double-quotes.